# Is there any way to invoke AWS Lambda from AWS EC2 backend without using API Gateway?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

Is there any way to invoke AWS Lambda from AWS EC2 backend without using API Gateway?
Java Spring Boot is used as the backend.

Previously, the backend (Java Spring Boot) was communicating with AWS Lambda through API Gateway, but I want to communicate with AWS Lambda directly without using API Gateway.

Comment: You can issue an `Invoke()` command to the AWS Lambda service. This can be done from anywhere on the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-java.html

The fact that it runs from an ec2 is not really relevant for this question but may require you to open up some permissions on the box